# Default for dropdown menu in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.6.  I am trying to work out whether there is a way to set a default for the option that appears in a dropdown box on the admin site (rather than the blank ------ option that appears). Specifically I am working with dropdown boxes for foreign keys, so they have no "choice" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropdown default can be set by specifying it in the foreign key field in **models.py** :

```
foreign_key_field = models.ForeignKey("keyname", default=1)
```

This will select the record with `id=1` in the corresponding admin dropdown by default. You may change `default=1` to any id that you want to show.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working for me.  I've added "default=1" to my model field definition as you suggest.  When I go to add a model of that kind through the "Add" interface in the admin site, the dropdown box still defaults to blank.

Comment: I just realised that I was setting the default field in the wrong place (in the definition of the table that I was referring to and not the ForeignKey reference.  Thanks!